# Glitch after resuming after hibernate

Tags: release-freya, greeter

Whenever my laptop goes into hibernate after inactivity it goes back to the login screen which is okay but whenever I log back in, the display starts misbehaving. When I say misbehaving, it bounces all over the place and starts duplicating itself. It rarely recovers and goes back to normal. What can I do to fix this?

Details: Elementary OS is running on my laptop(Dell Inspiron 15 5548) and is the only OS in my system.